# MYSQL Select One Random record from each Category

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

I have a database with an `Items` table that looks something like this:

```
id
name
category (int)
```

There are several hundred thousand records.  Each `item` can be in one of 7 different `categories`, which correspond to a `categories` table:

```
id
category
```

I want a query that chooses 1 random item, from each category.  Whats the best way of approaching that?  I know to use `Order By rand()` and `LIMIT 1`for similar random queries, but I've never done something like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This query returns all items joined to categories in random order:

```
SELECT
c.id AS cid, c.category, i.id AS iid, i.name
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN items i ON c.id = i.category
ORDER BY RAND()
```

To restrict each category to one, wrap the query in a *partial* `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    c.id AS cid, c.category, i.id AS iid, i.name
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN items i ON c.id = i.category
    ORDER BY RAND()
) AS shuffled_items
GROUP BY cid
```

Note that when a query has both `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clause, the grouping is performed before sorting. This is why I have used two queries: the first one sorts the results, the second one groups the results.

I understand that this query isn't going to win any race. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Above query works after a few corrections:
`SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    c.id as cid, c.category, i.id, i.name
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN Items i ON c.id = i.category
    ORDER BY RAND()
) AS ShuffeledItems
GROUP BY ShuffeledItems.cid`

Comment: Hm, this revised query is returning about 1500 rows for me

Comment: @SalmanA yeah, im not sure what to say.  I'm trying it out on my DB and it's returning about 1500 rows, and not the 7.

Comment: It's strange because here is groupping by category id so if you getting about 1500 rows, you have 1500 categories...

Comment: @rzymek ah nevermind, you are right.  I had a slightly different syntax in my table that was causing a problem!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rzymek would you like to create an answer or edit the existing one above?

Comment: @dtj, Salman A has already done it, I only make a few corrections :)
Nevertheless, I think this query may be done more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, name, category from Items where
( 
 select count(*) from Items i where i.category = Items.category 
 GROUP BY i.category ORDER BY rand()
) <= 1
```

REF: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: this one, I get an error that the sub query returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Let suppose you have this table.

```
id  name    category
1   A       1
2   B       1
3   C       1
4   D       2
5   E       2
6   F       2
7   G       3
8   H       3
9   I       3
```

Use this query

```
select
  c.id,
  c.category,
  (select name from category where category = c.category   group by id order by rand() limit 1) as CatName
from category as c
group by category
```

Comment: This one Im having trouble making sense of, as there seems to be no reference to the `items` tables, only the `categories` table

Comment: @dtj i dont have a keyword item in my query then what is confusing you? I have given you an example surely you can work out yourself after it.

Comment: are you sure the `GROUP BY` and `RAND()` will work together giving a random for each group? cause i doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Change order of the original table (random order), before final select:

```
select * from 
  (select category, id, name from categories order by rand()) as tab 
  group by 1
```

Comment: Please update you answer with some comments and how does it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from **mysql8** you can solve this by using **Windows functions**,
avoiding the extra join condition with `category` table

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

```
     SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY RAND()) AS first_id FROM items
     Order BY RAND()) AS r
     GROUP BY first_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note: in the following example I am assuming your table is named "items" not "Items" because you also said the other table was named "categories" (second table name not capitalized).

The SQL for what you want to do would roughly be:

```
`SELECT items.id AS item_id,
items.name AS item_name,
items.category AS item_category_id,
categories.id AS category_id,
categories.category AS category_name
FROM items, category
WHERE items.category = categories.id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1`
```

Comment: This query returns only one row. Without LIMIT 1 - all items from each category...

Comment: @ryzmek, yes, that's correct. This is also what the OP asked for, coincidentally. The OP said, and I quote:

"I want a query that chooses 1 random item, from each category"

Comment: In my opinion, the author expects query which returns 7 rows, one rand item for each category.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear.  The query should return 7 rows -- 1 corresponding to each item, from each category

Comment: this query is only returning one row