# Select n random rows per specified group

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to find an optimal solution for the following problem.

Suppose I have a table 'Table' like this:

```
id    name    report_id
 1    name1    1
 2    name2    3
 3    name3    5
 4    name1    7
 5    name3    8
 ....................
```

I want to select for each value in a set: ('name1', 'name2') 10 random unique rows.

Of course it is possible to do with *union* like:

```
(SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
    name='name1'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
    name='name2'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)
```

But if I have 100 unique names for which I have to select 10 random records - this query is going to be a bit large.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245275/mysql-select-one-random-record-from-each-category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27ff6/19)

```
select ID,NAME,REPORT_ID
from
(
select *, @row:=if(name=@name,@row,0)+1 as rn, @name:=name from 
(select *,RAND() as trand from t) t1,
(select @row:=0,@name:='') tm2 
order by name,trand
) t2
where rn<=10
```

Comment: @RedBaron Both queries will be generate identical plans.

Comment: @RedBaron . .  This answer is incorrect because it assumes that the expressions are evaluated in order.  MySQL *specifically* warns against this in the documentation.

Comment: Aren't there some conventions/standards for formatting the SQL, e.g. indentation?

Comment: @GordonLinoff in which case, leave a better answer here.

Comment: @user692942 . . . This is a question related to functionality in an old version of MySQL, and that functionality is now deprecated.  The question is 8 years old and the OP does not seem to be active on the site for 4 years.  Adding an answer here is useless, and helps no one, least of all someone who currently has a similar question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Whether the OP is active or not has no bearing on the usefulness of the question and a question that has been around as long as this is bound to garner attention and is already well established in search engines.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
    id, 
    name,
    report_id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id,
        report_id,
        name,
        CASE WHEN @name != name THEN @rn := 1 ELSE @rn := @rn + 1 END rn,
        @name:=name
     FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY RAND()) a,
        (SELECT @rn:=0, @name := NULL) r
     ORDER BY name
  ) s
  WHERE rn <= 10;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55629/13)**

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in MySQL, but in PostgreSQL you can use `partition by`

```
select name,report_id from
(select name,report_id,row_number()
over
(partition by name order by random())
as rn from Table) a
where rn<=10
```

I had this same question and found this answer from a colleague.