# random 2 records according to position and order by position

Tags: mysql

**question_tbl:**
q_id (int) PK, position (int), q_type (varchar(255)), question (varchar(255)), level (int)

Query i tried:

```
SELECT q_id, position, q_type, question, level
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_question ORDER BY rand()) a
WHERE level = '1'
ORDER BY position
```

And got below result:

```
q_id    position    qtn     level
1           1       demo      1
2           1       demo12    1
3           1       demo21    1
4           2       demo22    1
5           2       demo11    1
6           2       demo31    1
7           3       demo41    1
8           3       demo51    1
9           4       demo61    1
10          1       demo71    1
11          1       demo81    1
12          2       demo91    1
13          3       demo511   1
14          4       demo514   1
15          4       demo4511  1
```

**Expected result:**
random 2 records according to position and order by position as below:

```
q_id    position    qtn     level
2           1       demo12    1
3           1       demo21    1
4           2       demo22    1
5           2       demo11    1
7           3       demo41    1
8           3       demo51    1
9           4       demo61    1
15          4       demo4511  1
```

Want randome 2 records by position

Comment: Please provide with your table structure. Better provide with some `insert statements` too

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu see updated question

Comment: Let me check If I understood your question : You want 2 records of every position randomly. right?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu yes.

Comment: @Shadow that is not duplicate of that, that is already my question. read both the question

Comment: Used the wrong link. This question **is** a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854386/select-n-random-rows-per-specified-group

Comment: what is the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `position, rand()` so as to have a random order within each `position` partition. Then use variable to enumerate records of `position` partitions:

```
SELECT q_id, position, qtn, level, rn
FROM (
  SELECT q_id, position, qtn, level,
           @rn := IF(@pos = position, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@pos := position, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_question     
    WHERE level = '1'
    ORDER BY position, rand() ) a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @pos := 0) AS vars ) b
WHERE b.rn <= 2  
ORDER BY position
```

The outer query uses `@rn` to select just two records from each `position` partition.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be2359/3)

Answer (score 1):

You are just randomising and then re-ordering the whole set.

You only want 2 rows right?

So use LIMIT 2 to get only 2 in your inner query

```
SELECT q_id, position, q_type, question, level
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_question ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2) a
WHERE level = '1'
ORDER BY position
```

I think that's what you want.