# Sql for get last 3 rows for each level

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem. So, my table :

```
id      level      score
1        1          2
2        1          4
3        2          1
4        3          2
5        4          10
.......................
```

And I want to get for each level last 3 rows order by score desc. I tried like this :

```
select * from table order by score desc group by level LIMIT 3
```

But not work. Can you help me please ?
Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: may this link help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363047/random-2-records-according-to-position-and-order-by-position

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty gives you great solution already, this article is very useful as well: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several technique to do it and one way is to use user defined variable as

```
select id,`level`,score 
from (
  select *, 
  @rn:= if(@prev_level = `level`,@rn+1,1) as rn,
  @prev_level:= `level`
  from mytable,(select @rn:=0,@prev_level:=0)r
  order by `level`,score desc
)r
where r.rn <=3;
```

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94f30f/1)**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Solution:

```
select * from table t1
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    table  t
            WHERE t.level = t1.level AND 
                  t.score >= t1.score
        ) <= 3 order by t1.level, t1.score desc
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f367bb)

Comment: So working solutions get down vote in SO, as someone don't have understanding of SQL. BTW added SQLfiddle with test data to show its working