# Select query with Unique ID with no duplicates and random Subquery results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-8.0

I have the following query with a sub query:

```
SELECT 
    artists.name,
    tracks.track_name,
    m.member_name
FROM
    artists
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        RAND() AS seed, artist_id, member_name
    FROM
        artist_members
    GROUP BY seed
    ORDER BY seed) m ON m.artist_id = artists.id
        JOIN
    tracks ON tracks.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE
    artists.id = '1'
GROUP BY tracks.track_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

**sqlfiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3266ab/13

It works, besides, that it will give me the same artist member name and it's info (from Subquery) for all 12 results.

If I remove `GROUP BY album_tracks.track_code` it will give me random artist member names/info, which is good but can have duplicate `album_tracks.track_code` which I don't want.

I can't seem to find the balance on whatever I tried, 
I want to get random artist member names/info but NOT have the same  `album_tracks.track_code`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in the subquery. Why are you grouping by a random number? There probably won't be any duplicate `seed`, so that means there's no grouping at all.

Comment: Since each Artist can have a few band members I want to fetch a random member for an album_track column result. as it's a 1 to many sub query.

Comment: What's the different from just doing `ORDER BY RAND()`. I don't understand `GROUP BY seed`.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245275/mysql-select-one-random-record-from-each-category

Comment: @Barmar It randomizes the results - for some reason. it will give random member name every time you execute the query, if you remove it, it will always give the first member name. Using only `ORDER BY RAND()` without the `seed` will also give only first member name, for this query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What's the use of `seed`?

Comment: Edited question and added **sqlfiddle** which perfectly replicate the issue.

Comment: @Dror do you need: any random 4 members of the artist id = 1 **AND** any random 4 tracks of the artist id = 1 ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, regarding members, any members (duplicate is fine since I can also fetch higher LIMIT). Regarding tracks, any random tracks, but without duplicates.

Comment: @Dror does this work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2AjszWpjDj3LkQdfJxjHUB/0

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes thanks. the link seems to generate what I want to achieve. Looks pretty different than my query, now need to understand it :)

Comment: @Dror - WIthout `LIMIT 1`, the subquery can return multiple rows.  _This_ is probably the root of the problem.