Query a random group by result in Laravel
I'm attempting to execute the query below, where I group by two columns and aim to return a random result based on the group by.
$q = Sample::select('id')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->groupBy(['r_type', 'd_from'])
    ->get();

My table is structured as follows:
id | r_type | d_from
1  | 2      | pk
2  | 2      | pk
3  | 2      | pk
4  | 3      | in
5  | 3      | in
6  | 1      | id
7  | 1      | id

Currently, when I run the query, it does return the group. However, I want it to randomly return the array of ids it was grouped by.
example the query now returns an array like this
[ 1, 4, 6 ]
only. If it's random, i want it to return [3, 5, 7], [2,5,6] and so on
How can I achieve this in Laravel?

GROUP BY combines rows based on criteria, not puts them into a grouping order. So GROUP BY would return 2 rows, 1 | 2 | pk and 4 | 3 | pk. It's more for summaries and min/max functions. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/group-by-modifiers.html for usage

This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245275/mysql-select-one-random-record-from-each-category
